# Does DragonEgg support parameters like -fno-builtin in clang?

Tags: gcc, llvm

I have been using clang for quite a while, and I can use `clang -fno-builtin -emit-llvm -c hello.c` to prevent the generation of llvm built-in functions, such as `llvm.memset`.

Recently, I switched to gcc with DragonEgg, since the program to be built is originally designed to be compiled with gcc. I searched on the web, but did not find any information about how to set DragonEgg parameters.

Could anyone please give me some help? Any hint or reference will be welcomed. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have figured out a way to use `gcc` + `DragonEgg` to achieve similar effects myself.

```
gcc -S -c -O0 -fplugin=$(DRAGONEGG_SO) -fplugin-arg-dragonegg-emit-ir hello.c -o hello.bc
opt -O3 -disable-simplify-libcalls hello.bc -o hello.bc
```

`$(DRAGONEGG_SO)` is the path to `dragonegg.so`.

Basically the LLVM intrinsics are added by the optimization pass `instcombine`. With `-disable-simplify-libcalls`, the LLVM intrinsics are prevented from generating in `instcombine`.

The method should also work for `llvm-gcc` to generate LLVM IR without LLVM intrinsics.